# How can I map If over vectors?

Tags: list-manipulation

The righthand side of my assignment to `g` in the code shown below is not evaluating because `v` is a vector. How can I write the righthand side to work correctly.

```
m = 10
n = 5
r = 4
p := RandomInteger[]
c = Table[p, {i, m}, {j, n}]
t = Total[c, {2}]
avg = t/n
v = Function[If[0.5 <= # <= 1, 1, 0]] /@ avg
de = Abs[v - avg]
Total[de]
depcpp = Total[de]/n/m
x = Table[i + r - 1, {i, m}]
mode = Mod[x, r]
e = Function[If[# == 0, 1, 0]] /@ mode
g = Function[If[# == 1, v, g]] /@ e
dg = Abs[v - g]
Total[dg]
```

Comment: Have you seen `Part[]`?

Comment: What do you mean by `g = Function[If[# == 1, v, g]] /@ e`? I ask because `g` is undefined when the mapping occurs.

Comment: The culture here is to expect people to provide some code showing what they have done along with the question they have. After enough tries to fix this program I wonder whether it might be more helpful to you if you tried to clearly and simply explain what the goal of the program is. Given that I am guessing someone might be able to show a way to rewrite the whole program in a simpler fashion and help you accomplish what you are trying to get to.

Comment: I have looked into Part but I want the sections to reoccur and am not sure what that syntax would look like. I am attempting to model the difference between a system which updates every iteration and one which updates only every r which represents elections. It is a simple democratic deficiency model. Would setting an initial value of g help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`MapThread`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MapThread.html) is likely to be what you are looking for.

```
m = 10;
n = 5;
r = 4;
SeedRandom[42]; c = RandomInteger[1, {10, 5}];
avg = Total[c, {2}]/n
```

> `{3/5, 2/5, 1/5, 1/5, 1/5, 3/5, 2/5, 0, 4/5, 1}`

```
v = If[0.5 <= # <= 1, 1, 0] & /@ avg
```

> `{1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1}`

```
mode = Mod[r - 1 + Range[m], r]
```

> `{0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1}`

```
e = If[# == 0, 1, 0] & /@ mode
```

> `{1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0}`

I'm making up `u` because I don't want to deal with the recursion issue of having an undefined `g` appear in the this example.

```
SeedRandom[42]; u = RandomInteger[1, 10];
g = MapThread[If[#1 == 1, #2, #3] &, {e, v, u}]
```

> `{1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0}`

Comment: Maybe you can introduce the guy to `Boole[]`?

Comment: @J.M. I probably should, but I'm too tired to write another installment of my "Intro to Mathematica" right now. It's almost 2 AM where I'm sitting. I only want to deal with the specific issue the OP raised.

Comment: Thank you so much @m_goldberg MapThread is exactly what I needed. I will try to rewrite the program using Boole[]. This community is amazing and it is only with its help that I make fast progress learning mathematica.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just made a typo in your code .  Because I am not sure what you are looking to accomplished, my guest is that you meant to map the function g to the vector x.. Which returns an output.

```
  m = 10
n = 5
r = 4
p := RandomInteger[]
c = Table[p, {i, m}, {j, n}]
t = Total[c, {2}]
avg = t/n
v = Function[If[0.5 <= # <= 1, 1, 0]] /@ avg
de = Abs[v - avg]
Total[de]
depcpp = Total[de]/n/m
x = Table[i + r - 1, {i, m}]
mode = Mod[x, r]
e = Function[If[# == 0, 1, 0]] /@ mode

(* -------------Note that the conditional g is replaced with the \
vector x *)
g = Function[If[# == 1, v, x]] /@ e
(*------------  *)
dg = Abs[v - g]
Total[dg]
```

Hopefully , this will give you an idea what went wrong with your code.